# Dynamic generated fields and saving the data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have about 15 form fields(fieldset) which also has a large textarea(limit 4000 characters). I have to generate dynamically these set of fields when the button is clicked. I have to accommodate to create these fields n number of times(no limit). Does this design creates any issues while saving the data to MySQL database? Also What is best method to generate the fields dynamically and validate them? I appreciate any input.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the structure of your table that you are saving the data to??

Comment: There are 2 tables. One is to save the customer data and another one to save the details of the customer information. One to many relationship.

Comment: could you possibly save each textarea as a single row in the detail table or maybe make a linking table to the details id with a table with just the textareas?

Comment: The second table about 10 other fields with comments(textarea data).

Comment: you could make a linking table to the details id with multiple rows of textareas

Comment: Each detail id has one textarea. I can create a new table for only textareas. What if I limit these set of fields to max 10, does it create any problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4233/discussion-between-nav100-and-laurence-burke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I find more practical to generate the display of info entirely in js/jquery. This way, you don't have to handle the display in both languages. php sends an "empty" shell, with tiles and some static text, and a js file. The page js immediately ajax the data back from php, and formats it. If you do things carefully, you can reuse the procedure easily. I have gone as far as create types for each table fields, which tell how to display the field (id: "hidden", name: "text", county: "select", active: "checkbox", etc).

Moreover, I don't use any form, only buttons and the jquery $.post() function. This allows to build the post data easily with something like that:

```
$('table.VirtualFormTable').delegate('.update, .create', 'click', function() {  // .update and .create are button's class on each row.

    var $this = $(this);
    var $row = $this.closest('tr');
    params = {};
    $('input, select', $row).each(function () {
        if ( this.type == 'checkbox' ) params[this.name] = this.checked;
        params[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    if ( validateParams(params) ) {
        $.post(url, params, function (data) { $row.removeClass('updatePending'); });
    }

});
```

it's quite easy to loop each row that has changed, and build an "array" of params which looks like that:

```
{[ 
    0: {param1: '...', param2: '...'},
    1: {param1: '...', param2: '...'}
]}
```

then in php you can do something like that:

```
$fields = str_replace(array('true', 'false'), array('1', '0'), $_POST);  // transform checkboxes
$whereArray = array_slice($fields, 0, 1); // table_index in first position
myDbTools::insertOrUpdate('table', $fields, $whereArray);
```

with a 3 part template like that, you need to write 2 lines to create a complete form based on a table.

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery solution I did something similar once. If you've got some fieldset, you could take $('#yourfieldset').html() and append it to the last one, which is existing (so at first the first one). Then you could remove the data within these fieldset, like $('#yourfieldset input').val("").
So you've got the duplicating, and you could also create a little function to duplicate it several times.

For the saving, you could change the name-attributes of the fieldset, which you are copying. Something like:

```
$('#yourfieldset input').each(function() {
 $(this).attr("name",  $(this).attr("name") + "_" + counter);
});
```

You need that counter as variable as global of course, to count the fieldsets up. To remove a fieldset, its also possible to just give the function this counter or lets call it rownumber. So you could delete it with $('#yourfieldset["id$=_15"]').remove() because it looks for the id attribute with the specific number and removes that fieldset.

In PHP you can iterate through the POST vars, which should be very easy. Do some print_r() for the data to see, how it looks like.

Comment: I have used JQuery clone method to generate these fields. But I am not sure how to validate them on the client side and server side.

Comment: Clone is possible as well. A validator you can find here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation
And if you give those input fields the right classes, and copy them, its no problem. And on the server side you have to iterate through the array anyway, so you can check each value again.